# Ajax request for PHP to return HTML

Tags: php, ajax

I have an element on a page that when clicked will make an ajax request to a `receiver.php` file:

```
<script>
function send(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'receiver.php',
        data: {id: id}
    });
}
</script>

<img src="foo.bar" onclick="send(id)"/> <!-- simplified -->
```

My idea is that this `receiver.php` file will receive the `id`, then output a whole page of HTML based on that `id`

However, when I click on the element, the new HTML page that I expect doesn't show up. When I go to the Chrome inspector, Network tab I can see the request and the response is exactly the HTML content I need, but why doesn't it change to that new page and stay on the old page instead?

EDIT: This is my `receiver.php`, for testing purpose:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<p>".$_POST['comid']."</p>";
        echo "<p> foo foo </p>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the response:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>3</p><p> foo foo </p>    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Try debugging the script** by catching the ajax response. For example: `$.ajax(...).done(function(response){ console.log(response); });`. _More details on this in the [jQuery Ajax Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)._

Comment: Can you show us what the `receiver.php` script does? Perhaps that's where the error resides (because your AJAX request is fine).

Comment: @Markus the response is the HTML content, the same as I saw in the Chrome inspector

Comment: because you are not performing any action with the response of the request no success no complete function to get the response

Comment: @Chin Play around with the `.success()` and `.fail()` functions. See what each returns. You can place `console.log()` _(or `console.warn()` for better readability if more messages show up in your console)_ everywhere, maybe place a return; after it to stop script execution. Repeat this moving forward _step by step_ until you find the problematic source (so the point where the script starts being defiant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps in your `receiver.php` script you're doing something like this, where you determine which HTML page to output depending on the id that it is receiving.

```
switch ($_POST['id']) {
case 'foo':
    $filepath = 'bar';
    break;

    ...
}

readfile($filepath);
```

You would have to *reflect* that in your AJAX query, using the `success` function of [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
function send(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'receiver.php',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (data) {
            // Replace the whole body with the new HTML page
            var newDoc = document.open('text/html', 'replace');
            newDoc.write(data);
            newDoc.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do something with the result that comes back from you AJAX call:

```
function send(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'receiver.php',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```